# Obtaining a list of connected clients for a wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-3.5, ip, net.tcp

How can I enumerate some sort of location identifier for all of the connected clients for a servicehost? I'm using a duplex connection for long running calculations. The Service host is a singleton.

I can figure out (in .net 3.5) the ip of the calling client but i am unsure how to get the ip of all connected clients.

Answer (score 2):

By default, WCF promotes the use of "per-call" services, e.g. your client calls, the request gets handled, and then the client is disconnected again right away.

WCF doesn't lend itself too well for and isn't intended for long-running connections - so you can't really "enumerate the currently connected users" since there aren't any (or only for a  fraction of a second).

WCF is not like a Windows domain server where you log in and stay logged in for an extended period of time.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear in my post but I'm not using the default service behavior.
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]

With InstanceContexMode.Single there is one instance with a longer lifespan than the default "per-call" mode.

The service as implemented currently uses a callback contract to send the results when they are ready.

The client caches it's connection with the server so that they may be used for multiple requests. The connections are long-running.

Comment: OK - I don't think that's a very good idea, but I don't know the details of your setup; unfortunately, in WCF 3.5, there's not a whole lot of support for management and surveillance - this will be part of the "Dublin" project - a management add-on to IIS7/WAS scheduled to ship some time after .NET 4 (March 2010).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything built-in for that, but it'd be pretty easy to build a tracking IServiceBehavior + IDispatchMessageInspector that would inspect the RemoteClientEnpointMessageProperty before the call is dispatched to the service impl and stick the client IP into a shared list, and remove it when the call/session ends.